# Unable to locate package default-jdk on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: java, jdk

I am trying to install Java on my system.

when i run
`sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

I get

> E: Unable to locate package default-jdk

and before that i used
`sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

and got:

```
>Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                     
.
.
.
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
.
.
.
yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vlc/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
.
.
.
Fetched 2,802 B in 18s (154 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vlc/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vlc/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I also tried fixing the PPA repositories but i'm not exactly sure i'm in the right direction with this.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It happened to me before, although my release version was a supported one (sometimes oracle repo updates Java and ppa tries to download installer from the old link).

In this [link](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+index?field.series_filter=yakkety) you can see the following:

*Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak is no longer supported by Canonical (and thus, Launchpad and this PPA). The PPA supports Ubuntu 17.10, 17.04, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04.*

Although, if you require to install Java in Ubuntu, I'd rather recommend to install directly .tar.gz file from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), follow the instructions for installing, you just need to uncompress .tar.gz file and update alternatives for Java as this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps) explain.